# How can I make my Gradle plugin auto-execute its tasks?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I’ve written a plugin (which currently just lives in buildSrc) that creates several tasks whose names are based on values provided by the user. How can I make it so that they execute whenever the build script that applies the plugin is run? It doesn't need to run at any specific point in the execution phase.

Comment: First, why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? And second, when in the build do you want to run them? At the end? Do they have any dependencies? Or any inputs? Or do they depend on a specific type of task? Or do those tasks depend on it? There are ways to do this, but it will depend on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @mkobit It's an Android project, and all that matters is that the tasks finish before the app starts. That's hardly a restriction, since I'm pretty sure Gradle isn't even responsible for pushing and starting the app. There's no dependencies or inputs, they're totally self-contained. It's fine if they run even if no devices are connected or the current task isn't even a build (clean, for example). If possible, I'd like to have the code that runs the tasks live within the plugin, rather than the build script.

Comment: "If possible, I'd like to have the code that runs the tasks live within the plugin, rather than the build script." Everything you can do in a build script is also possible within a plugin.

Comment: Here's a really good real-world example of how to do this for an Android project: https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin/blob/b1fbef8f8d4d14749d2727eaaef65d39a7652ab1/src/main/kotlin/com/getkeepsafe/dexcount/Plugin.kt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off with, you work around a basic Gradle concept. A Gradle **task** is not designed to run on every Gradle invocation. If you really need code to run on each Gradle invocation, execute it directly during *configuration phase* instead of wrapping it inside a **task**.

However, there are two causes for a **task** to run on a Gradle build:

- direct selection (via command line or `settings.startParameter.taskNames` modification)
- via one or more task dependencies (`dependsOn` / `finalizedBy`)

Of course you can use one of these methods to circumvent Gradle and execute your **task** on each build (@mkobit used the second method), but since your plugin would basically break basic Gradle principles, your solution may fail at some future time or for a more complex project (since plugins are supposed to be reusable).

As a summary, I would recommend to bundle all your generated tasks in one task with a constant name, so that your user can easily run the task on each Gradle invocation by putting a single line in his `settings.gradle` file:

```
startParameter.taskNames.add '<bundleTask>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I didn't know about `settings.startParameter.taskNames`. I really really like that idea.

Comment: I added a recommendation on how to work on your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a really solid solution. I think I'm going to go that route. Part of me is tempted to run my code during the configuration phase, but that feels kinda "wrong".

Comment: Good answer, and I agree with everything here. There may be some use cases where you do want to always run a task (say like reporting, metrics, etc.) but in most cases you want to structure your tasks in terms of inputs and outputs and the dependencies between them.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could accomplish this is to use the `all` method on the `TaskCollection` to add a [`dependsOn`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependsOn-java.lang.Object...-)/[`finalizedBy`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy-java.lang.Object...-) relationship to all (or some) tasks in the project.

Example to create a single `myTask` with every task in `allproject` depending on it:

```groovy
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(final Project project) {
    final myTask = project.tasks.create('myTask')
    project.allprojects.each { proj ->
      proj.tasks.all {
        // Make sure to not add a circular dependency
        if (it != myTask) {
          it.dependsOn(myTask)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```